# Casting mistake

Tags: c#, wpf, casting, listbox, entity

Currently, in course, I am trying to check the `LandCode` from the class `Landen` to get the cities from the `selectedItem` land, but I am parsing something wrong.

```
public partial class Landen
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Landen()
    {
        this.Steden = new HashSet<Steden>();
        this.Talen = new HashSet<Talen>();
    }

    public string LandCode { get; set; }
    public string Naam { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Steden> Steden { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Talen> Talen { get; set; }
}



public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var context = new LandenStedenTalenEntities();
    landenListBox.ItemsSource = (from Landen in context.Landen select Landen.Naam).ToList();
}

private void landenListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var entities = new LandenStedenTalenEntities())
    {
        List<string> steden = new List<string>();
        var landcode = ((Landen)landenListBox.SelectedItem).LandCode.ToString();
        var gekozenland = entities.Landen.Find(landcode);

        foreach(var stad in gekozenland.Steden)
        {
            steden.Add(stad.Naam);
        }
        stedenInLandenListBox.ItemsSource = steden.ToList();
    }
}
```

Exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'TestEFDieter.Landen'.

I want to add them to a list and show them in a second Listbox.
Can anyone help me out? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Where is your error?

Comment: var landcode = ((Landen)landenListBox.SelectedItem).LandCode.ToString();  
Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'TestEFDieter.Landen'.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this `.ToString().ToList();`? String is already a "char array" and you can iterate through it just by calling indexers.

Comment: It's called hopeless trying to find something without thinking -_-'

Comment: The `SelectedItem` obviously contains a string, which isn´t convertable to `Landen`. We don´t know what `Landen` is and how you´re plaling to get an instance of that class by whatever you selected in your listbox.

Comment: Updated, sorry new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you modify the code inside of the constructor so that the `landenListBox` will contain actual `Landen` object and displays only the `Naam` as it's item.

Change the code in the constructor to this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var context = new LandenStedenTalenEntities();
    landenListBox.ItemsSource = context.Landen.ToList();
    landenListBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Naam";
}
```

Adding [`DisplayMemberPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath(v=vs.110).aspx) will inform `ListBox` to display that particular property as an item instead of calling `ToString()` method on that object.

Now in your later code you do not have to change much, just remove `ToList()` and since you're using `EntityFramework` you should insert the whole model in it's `Find()` method but it's useless since you already have that object loaded. You can just retrieve `stad` from it directly and display it in the same way `Landen` is displayed:

```
private void landenListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var landen = landenListBox.SelectedItem as Landen; // safe cast just in case
    if (landen != null && landen.Steden != null ) // null checks
    {
        stedenInLandenListBox.ItemsSource = landen.Steden.ToList(); // in case it's proxy object
        stadenInLandenListBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Naam";
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm and nice explanation, thank you sir! Thumbs up

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to get that instance of `Landen` which corresponds the selected item in your list. As the elements in the listbox are just strings that represent the `Naam`-property of every `Landen`, you could simply iterate your list of `Landen` and get that one with the desired `Naam`:

```
var selectedLanden = landenList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Naam == landenListBox.SelectedItem);
if(selectedLanden != null)
{
    var landCode = selectedLanden.LandCode;
    // ...
}
```

However as `selectedLanden` already *is* an instance of `Landen`, you won´t need to find it again by its `LandCode`. Thus your code boils donw to this:

```
List<string> steden = new List<string>();
var selectedLanden = landenList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Naam == landenListBox.SelectedItem);
if(selectedLanden != null)
{
    foreach(var stad in selectedLanden.Steden)
    {
        steden.Add(stad.Naam);
    }
}
stedenInLandenListBox.ItemsSource = steden.ToList();
```

or a bit shorter:

```
stedenInLandenListBox.ItemsSource = selectedLanden.SelectMany(x => x.Steden.Select(y => y.Naam)).ToList();
```

For this to work you of course have to store a reference to the list of `Landen` somewehere in your class:

```
class MainWindow
{
    List<Landen> landenList;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.landenList = new LandenStedenTalenEntities();
        landenListBox.ItemsSource = (from Landen in this.landenList select Landen.Naam).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: The  landenlistbox works how I posted it,  I just want to show the Cities with the Selected Land's LandCode in a second Listbox

Comment: please show exactly where the error occurs **in your question**

Comment: Thank you for the comment sir! Thumbs up